# Shifting Gmail files into different order

Tags: gmail

When I used Outlook, I could just grab the file (from the left column with all of the files listed) and move it to any position within the list. This way I could keep my not-ready-to archive-but-not-ready-to-remove emails at the bottom of the list.

I can't figure out how to do this in Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail go to
 `1. Settings` >
`2. Inbox` >
`3. Pick` an option (different than Default) >
`4. Customise` as you wish with as many sections >
`5. Configure` every sections as you wish (with labels, important, starred, etc..)

[image]